# Static variable's scope in instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have confusion for below snippet of Python static variables. when i execute i will be accessing instance variable. But if i comment out line #3 .Then will be accessing static variable . I want to know why instance method behaves like this.

```
class Test:
     static_variable = "this is static variable"

     def __init__(self):
            self.static_variable= "this is some instance variable" # 3

     def some_method(self):
             print(self.static_variable)

t = Test()
t.some_method()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of an answer you are expecting. It's just how the language works. It's like asking why `def` defines a function

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki . its class level variable with just name static_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `self`, which is the instance itself, the lookup will happen in the instance's scope and fallback to the class's scope.

In your case, if you are assigning the variable in the `__init__`, then it will be resolved first, if not the class attribute will be resolved.

Comment: I had this confusion regarding scope  .Thanks for clarification  @satvyk

Answer (score 0):

You can access class attributes using `self` or `Test`

```
print(self.static_variable)
print(Test.static_variable)
```

But if you overwrite the `self.static_variable` then the 2 calls just above won't return the same value and this

```
class Test:
    static_variable = "this is static variable"

    def __init__(self):
        self.static_variable = "this is some instance variable"  # 3

    def some_method(self):
        print(self.static_variable)
        print(Test.static_variable)
# will give this
this is some instance variable
this is static variable
```

The class attribute `static_variable` is first only a class attribute, then it exists as a class attribute AND an instance attribute

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, it feels like a rephrasing of it. OP knows all that. They are asking "why", and the answer to that is "because that's what the language designers decided".

Answer (score 0):

In python, everything is object when static variable defined at class level becomes an attribute of a class.
When an instance is created of a class, and we defined the same name as an attribute at the instance level, then we do override the attribute defined at class level. Ideally, static variables are supposed to be with `Class.MethodName`.
Try this:

```
class Test:
     static_variable = "this is static variable"

     def __init__(self):
         self.static_variable= "this is some instance variable" # 3

     def some_method(self):
         print(self)
         print(Test.static_variable)
         print(self.static_variable)

t = Test()
t.some_method()
```